# Android : Need to convert a Linear Layout to ? to allow 2 columns on each row - approx. 80% 20%

Tags: android

I currently have a LinearLayout with 5 rows.

I now need to have 2 columns on my rows, I've tried using GridLayout with no joy.

But I'm wondering what the best solution is anyway:
TableLayout / Constraintlayout?

Comment: Please share a screenshot that can show a demonstration of what you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Use Constraintlayout with "layout_constraintWidth_percent and layout_constraintHeight_percent : will set the size of this dimension as a percentage of the parent"

Because TableLayout "The width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in that column. However, a TableLayout can specify certain columns as shrinkable or stretchable"

Thus TableLayout is more about the row items in the column being able to take all the space they need while keeping the column aligned, not giving a certain percentage to each row item in the column

As long as you give row items the same percentage the row items in the column will align.